# Entity Model 3.5 COMPATIBILITY

Tags: entity-framework

Can we use same Entity Model with sql compact file which is generated by sql server database.

I need to convert the sqlserver database to sql compact file and need to know if same model can be use in application or we need to generate the model again.

Tool: VS 2008 TEAM AND C#

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. 
But please don't forget to change the connection string, Provider and ProviderManifestToken attributes of the generated .edmx file.
Devart Team 
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect 
ADO.NET data providers for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite with
Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL support